# How do I type Macrons on an Android device?

Tags: resource-request, latin-on-devices

How do I type Macrons on an Android device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ā, ă, ē, ĕ, ī, ū are all easily typable on an Android device by long-pressing the corresponding vowel. So ĭ, ŏ, ō, ŭ, ȳ and y̆ are missing.

For Samsung, I'll quote a post from [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/468670-where-macron-letter-o-galaxy-s5-samsung-keyboard.html%3famp), but only in part because that procedure doesn't seem to work for me:

1. In your browser, find and copy the letter you need from any site.
2. Go to Settings > Language and input > Samsung keyboard > Predictive text > Text shortcuts.
3. Here, you can set keyboard shortcuts for whenever you write a certain word. Add a shortcut with your copied letter, and naturally set the corresponding vowel as the needed input for the shortcut to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Swype keyboard, which has macra available for all vowels except y, by long-pressing the letter. So you could use that.

Comment: Actually this seems to be true of the standard android keyboard! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Google Keyboard (GBoard), add the Māori language, and select it while typing by long press on the spacebar.

Then macrons are really easy: just a long press on a vowel, and it switches to the one with a macro.

Comment: Based on your recomendation, I just switched to Maori in Windows 10; however, I have to press the "tilde" key below the ESC key before pressing the vowel to get a macron.